# How to call functions bundled in webpack encore

Tags: javascript, webpack-encore

Is it possible to call a function from webpack compiled JS file? Whenever I try to do it I get an error message saying "function_name is not defined".

Comment: You should be able to call your function from inside the compiled JS file. I need more info to help you further https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I need to call from some other file or directly in html file

Comment: Can you post the webpack file and the name of your function? I can work it out how to access it, but I need the file content.